# OpenJPA enhancing a Spring ROO batch application

Tags: java, spring-roo, openjpa

I'm quite new to OpenJPA and wanted to run my application. I've made a main method and load the context XML there and fire up a transaction to run my service in. But when I run it I get a

org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The type "class tld.myproject.domain.Entity" has not been enhanced.

I Google'd around and found that I'd need to add an enhancer, so I added the following to my command line:

-javaagent:/home/me/.m2/repository/org/apache/openjpa/openjpa/2.0.1/openjpa-2.0.1.jar

Now, I get

java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "org/springframework/stereotype/Controller"

Perhaps it's just getting late and I don't have my head screwed right on, but, what on earth is going on here? What do I need to do to get my Spring Roo batch project running?

Cheers

Nik

PS, I should probably add that in my pom.xml Roo has defined an enhancer for the compile phase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use compile time enhancement instead of runtime enhancement with javaagent.

If you're using m2eclipse (you probably do) it would be enough to use something like:

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.H2Dictionary"/>
        <!-- value="buildSchema" to runtime forward map the DDL SQL; value="validate" makes no changes to the database -->
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/>
        <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and inside build section of your pom.xml you should have something like:

```
                      <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>openjpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>**/*.class</includes>
                            <excludes>**/*_Roo_*.class</excludes>
                            <addDefaultConstructor>true</addDefaultConstructor>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>enhancer</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>enhance</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>test-enhancer</id>
                                <phase>test-compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>enhance</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
                                <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
                                <version>${openjpa.version}</version>
                                <exclusions>
                                    <exclusion>
                                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                                    </exclusion>
                                    <exclusion>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                                    </exclusion>
                                </exclusions>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                    </plugin>
```

Please note that roo might generate different xml snippet that might not work (IIRC it uses different output directory).

After you clean your project classes should be enhanced.